# Hyper-V Won't Enable in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, bios, virtualization, hyper-v

So, I'm trying to develop an app for WP8, however I can't seem to make the emulator run... Why? Hyper-V won't enable!

I'm using a AMD FDX 8350 processor in a 970A-UD3 Gigabyte motherboard.

Here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj863509(v=vs.105).aspx, Microsoft tells you to enable NP/RVI, SVM and NX in the BIOS and to disable Intel VT-d (only for Intel CPUs maybe?) and Trusted Execution, well, I was able to find SVM in my BIOS configuration and it was enabled by default... However, I can't find any of the others there so I'm not sure if they are properly configured or not, I've search all the BIOS menus and couldn't find anything rather then SVM.

Even only being able to confirm SVM, I tried to turn on Hyper-V through the Control Panel. It goes fine until the reboot... When Windows is turning off it begins to configure some changes, the strange thing is, that it only goes up to 30% and reboot, then upon coming back up it start applying the changes and goes only to 73% and fails... Then reboot again... Then try to "Configure Windows" then it tries to apply some updates (what?) and then fails at 73% again, then reboot... Then try again... Then fail... Then reboot... After 3 or 4 reboots it finally takes me to the desktop and guess what? Hyper-V is not there.

So the thing is... Someone that's using a Gigabyte motherboard knows how can I check for the missing features that I couldn't find and see if they are on or not? Because their buggy visual interfaced BIOS is completely worthless with so many missing options.

Comment: this is a Windows issue. Upload the folder C:\Windows\logs\CBS so that I can see what is wrong.

Comment: Download the [AMD Virtualization Technology and Microsoft Hyper-V System Compatibility Check Utility](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/taylorb/archive/2008/06/19/hyper-v-will-my-computer-run-hyper-v-detecting-intel-vt-and-amd-v.aspx) to determine if Hyper-V is even supported by your hardware.  The link to the tool appears dead but the rest of the article is helpful

Comment: @Ramhound if the CPU doesn't support VT the checkbox is grayed out. He has a Windows servicing issue, but I need the logs.

Comment: @magicandre1981 here's the CBS: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=783CE87CB59F418E!1108&authkey=!AO9Tk3nwoBDFTZc&ithint=file%2c.rar

Comment: I think I'll need help from someone again... @magicandre1981 found out the problem, but I'll need a new winsxs\manifests\amd64_microsoft-windows-s..ingstack-base-extra_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.16470_none_0fca1bd2974614ab.manifest files from a different computer, however the only other computer I have here is Intel, could someone upload it?

Answer (score 1):

You get the Error `8007007e` which means `ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND`:

```
C:\Users\André>err 8007007e
# as an HRESULT: Severity: FAILURE (1), FACILITY_WIN32 (0x7), Code 0x7e
# for hex 0x7e / decimal 126
  ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND                                            winerror.h
# The specified module could not be found.
# 1 matches found for "8007007e"
```

because a files of the servicing stack (`winsxs\manifests\amd64_microsoft-windows-s..ingstack-base-extra_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.16470_none_0fca1bd2974614ab.manifest`),the component which install updates, activates features in Windows since Vista is corrupted.

```
2014-02-22 14:22:07, Info                  CSI    000000a4 Begin executing advanced installer phase 24 (0x00000018) index 131 (0x0000000000000083) (sequence 156)
    Old component: [ml:330{165},l:328{164}]"Microsoft-Hyper-V-Drivers-Hypervisor-Bcd, Culture=neutral, Version=6.3.9600.16384, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, ProcessorArchitecture=amd64, versionScope=NonSxS"
    New component: [l:0]""
    Install mode: uninstall
    Installer ID: {3eca0b00-79bb-42b9-8421-a26a5cbb37e4}
    Installer name: [41]"Boot Configuration CSI Advanced installer"
2014-02-22 14:22:07, Info                  CSI    000000a5 Manifest hash for component [ml:280{140},l:200{100}]"amd64_microsoft-windows-s..ingstack-base-extra_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.16470_none_0fca1bd2974614ab" does not match expected value. 
 Expected:{l:32 b:5a1656a028f53682db2b0f6f8bbd463d09d9796905d8de4240739169431ee24d}
 Found:{l:32 b:2a104ce3fa57b5115405c252f96d77ac0eda17b8a373762aa5db28afe68ebee0}.
2014-02-22 14:22:07, Info                  CSI    000000a6 Looking for manifest in Backup Dir...
2014-02-22 14:22:07, Error                 CSI    000000a7 (F) Unable to load manifest for component [ml:280{140},l:200{100}]"amd64_microsoft-windows-s..ingstack-base-extra_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.16470_none_0fca1bd2974614ab"[gle=0x80004005]
2014-02-22 14:22:07, Error                 CSI    000000a8@2014/2/22:17:22:07.364 (F) base\wcp\componentstore\storelayout.cpp(2158): Store corruption detected in function ComponentStore::CRawStoreLayout::FetchManifestContent expression: 0
  FileHashMismatch on resource [127]"\winsxs\manifests\amd64_microsoft-windows-s..ingstack-base-extra_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.16470_none_0fca1bd2974614ab.manifest"[gle=0x80004005]
2014-02-22 14:22:07, Info                  CSI    000000a9 ERROR MAPPING HRESULT - No proper NTSTATUS mapping available.  Error is: "c015001a [Error,Facility=(0015),Code=26 (0x001a)]".

2014-02-22 14:22:07, Info                  CSI    000000aa@2014/2/22:17:22:07.676 Failed to load CSI AI DLL from keyform; falling back to Base-SS directory.

2014-02-22 14:22:07, Error                 CSI    000000ab@2014/2/22:17:22:07.676 (F) base\wcp\componentstore\com\advancedinstallers.cpp(80): Error HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND) originated in function LoadHandlerDll expression: ((HRESULT)(::GetLastError()) <= 0 ? ((HRESULT)(::GetLastError())) : ((HRESULT) (((::GetLastError()) & 0x0000FFFF) | (7 << 16) | 0x80000000)))
[gle=0x80004005]
```

Because  servicing stack is corrupted, [DISM](http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2012/09/26/fixing-component-store-corruption-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx) and [sfc](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833) can't be used to repair Windows.

You must [grab a good copy of the file from a second PC which has the Update KB2904440 installed, and replace the bad file with the clean copy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee619779%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks a lot... I'll just need to find someone who's running Windows 8.1 as well... Probably I'll just re-image my notebook with Windows 8 and copy the files from it to my desktop.

Comment: Ahm... We have a problem here, I could copy the file from my laptop, however the problem is that the laptop has a Intel CPU and I noticed that this might be a specific file for AMD processors... Darn it

Comment: AMD64 is the codename of the 64Bit Windows. AMD created the first 64Bit x86 CPU, so MS used this codename. This has nothing to to with AMD or Intel CPU that you use.

Comment: Ok, I know that's anoying, but I got another problem. I was able to instal the KB2904440 in my laptop and copy the manifest file from it, however when I try to replace the corrupted one in my desktop it is denying me access, in that article from Microsoft there's a mean to grant you full admin access to the file but I'm getting stuck in the icacls command, it is saying that the mapping between the acount name and the security identificativos were not done (I don't know if that's the exact message, since my Winows is not in english), anyway I can't get any further from here

Comment: use this GUI tool to take ownership of the file: http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.18

Comment: Ok so, I was able to replace the manifest file, but that did not solve all the problem... No it goes further, up to 98% (before it was going only to 73%) but then fails just like before.

Comment: delete the old logs from C:\Widows\Logs\CBS, try to activate Hyper-V again and share the new logs.

Comment: There you go... https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=783CE87CB59F418E!1292&authkey=!ADtdNAL9SZqPB8w&ithint=file%2c.log

Comment: this time the **sppinst.dll** is missing from folder **C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-servicingstack_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.16470_none_fa2491fd9b3cfcb2**.

Comment: Weird... I don't have this dll even on my laptop from were I picked the manifest file.

Comment: backup all data and reinstall Windows. It is damaged too heavily.